# how to format output of Join RDD using java

Tags: java, join, apache-spark

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Double>> accountNew = 
        accountRecPair.join(accountCnt).join(accountSum);
```

```
( Key,   (value))
------------------------------
(12,(ID1,12,1062.0,2),68605.0))
```

i would like myoutput without "(" and ")"

---

```
ID1,12,1062.0,2,68605.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since tuples are not collections (they are more like case classes), there is no easy way to flatten the structure. You have to explicitly map your result after each join to extract the data the nested tuple structure and put them in a flat tuple structure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, If you don't mind, can you please share code snippet on how to flatten, then I will take forward, I new to Java, I learned java to use BIG data tools. Again thanks for the reply

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure what is the structure of you data since there either a lack of coherence or explanations to your snippets of code

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaRDD<String> outputFile = accountNew.map(
    new Function< Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Double>>, String>() {

        public String call(
                Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Double>> rec)
                 {
                    String orderRec ;
                  //  orderRec = rec._1 ;
                    Tuple2<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Double> rec1 = rec._2() ;
                    Tuple2<String, Integer> rec2 = rec1._1() ;

                    orderRec = rec2._1 + "," + rec2._2().toString() + "," + rec1._2().toString() ;

                    return orderRec;
                  }         
    }
) ;
```

Here is what I did to format the output.

> Blockquote